# No module named motionchart.motionchart python import error

Tags: python

i installed motion chart 
pip install motionchart
and tried to import throughs an error

```
Requirement already satisfied: motionchart in ./.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages
Requirement already satisfied: setuptools in ./anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages
ImportError Traceback (most recent call last)
in ()
1 get_ipython().system(u'pip install motionchart ')
2 get_ipython().system(u'pip install setuptools')
----> 3 from motionchart.motionchart import MotionChart, MotionChartDemo
4 import pandas as pd
5 import time

ImportError: No module named motionchart.motionchart
```

Comment: try `from motionchart import MotioChart`

Comment: Tried this didn't work